# Export animated displacement modifier to Unity

Tags: animation, unity

I created some water in blender by using an empty axis to animate a displace modifier on a water mesh that I created. I animated it but when I export to unity the animation does not run. Am I doing something wrong? If so then what way is the best way to create water in blender for unity. Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can't expect to export complex animations nor modifier effects from Blender to any other application. You might be able to accomplish something equivalent by baking said effect to an animated normal map, then use that in Unity, maybe.